# How to combine two plot objects (non ggplot)

Tags: r, plot

I have the following code:

```
library(UpSetR)

listInput <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 
                                                                 10), three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13))

p <- upset(fromList(listInput), order.by = "freq")
jpeg(filename = "test.jpg")
print(p)
dev.off()
```

Which produces plot like this:

[image]

As stated in the plot above I want to add a text `MY_TITLE` on top of it. I tried this but failed:

```
t <- grid.text("MY_TITLE", x = 0.65, y = 0.95, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))
np <- p +  t
jpeg(filename = "test.jpg")
print(np)
dev.off()
```

What's the right way to do it?
Not that I want to store the combined figures into an object. Because I need to do `print()` to save as file
afterward.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ggplot grammar and syntax on base plots. Don't use `+`, just plot the text code under the `print(p)` call like so:

```r
jpeg(filename = "test.jpg")
print(p)
grid.text("MY_TITLE", x = 0.65, y = 0.95, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10))
dev.off()
```

That then gives you what you want.[image]